# No keyboard after login in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, xorg, 20.04, xorg.conf

I post this forum because I have a problem and I have a lot of trouble finding answers
I'm on an Asus Zenbook UX480F with Ubuntu 20 on it and no more keyboard works after I open my Gnome session
By "no more keyboard" I mean that the integrated keyboard does not work, but no USB keyboard either! (at least my touchpad is working)

I'm an Ubuntu beginner and I tried to reconfigure the keyboard, doesn't work...

This is why I implore your help, I am a developer and code with a visual keyboard, frankly it's not crazy!
Thank you in advance for your precious help :)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. XUbuntu 20.04 reinstall and now no keyboard. Using expensive Logitech wired USB keyboard, US layout.  Not picked up at all during boot selection and after Ubuntu loads have only partial capability.  Can't login to SE for example. Keyboard always worked before.

Comment: Do you also have a Zenbook UX480F like me ? I don't really know if this problem is only for that specific model

Comment: No this is a 12 yr old desktop.  It was running XUbuntu 20.04 just fine with the newer Logitech keyboard for months. Then when I did a reinstall of XUbuntu 20.04, the keyboard wouldn't work anymore.